# Got Junk Error Message from assembler while Compiling Trilinos Source Code

Tags: gcc, assembly, gnu, gfortran, trilinos

I am compiling Trilinos from source code and got an error which complains junk parts. My kernel version 3.13.0 and my g++ version is 4.8.2. I am running on x86_64 machine. The error message looks like this:

```
scalar_field.s:24649: Error: junk `@104.5037' after expression
```

The command run is

```
cd /home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/ForTrilinos/example/ADT_3D_Burgers_6th_Pade && /usr/bin/gfortran   -ffree-line-length-none -g -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ForTrilinos/src/epetra -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ForTrilinos/src/teuchos -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ForTrilinos/src/amesos -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ForTrilinos/src/aztecoo -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ForTrilinos/src/galeri -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ForTrilinos/src/ifpack -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ForTrilinos/src/pliris -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/ForTrilinos/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ForTrilinos/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/ForTrilinos/src/mod -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/CTrilinos/src/epetra -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/CTrilinos/src/teuchos -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/CTrilinos/src/amesos -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/CTrilinos/src/aztecoo -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/CTrilinos/src/galeri -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/CTrilinos/src/ifpack -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/CTrilinos/src/pliris -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/CTrilinos/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/CTrilinos/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/ifpack/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ifpack/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ifpack/../amesos/src/SuiteSparse/AMD/Include -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ifpack/../amesos/src/SuiteSparse/UFconfig -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/amesos/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/amesos/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/amesos/src/SuiteSparse/AMD/Include -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/amesos/src/SuiteSparse/COLAMD/Include -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/amesos/src/SuiteSparse/CHOLMOD/Include -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/amesos/src/SuiteSparse/UFconfig -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/amesos/src/SuiteSparse/KLU/Include -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/amesos/src/SuiteSparse/BTF/Include -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/amesos/src/SuiteSparse/CAMD/Include -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/epetraext/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/epetraext/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/epetraext/src/transform -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/epetraext/src/inout -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/epetraext/src/coloring -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/epetraext/src/model_evaluator -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/epetraext/src/block -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/epetraext/src/restrict -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/triutils/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/triutils/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/epetra/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/epetra/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/teuchos/kokkoscomm/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/teuchos/kokkoscomm/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/teuchos/kokkoscompat/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/teuchos/kokkoscompat/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/teuchos/parameterlist/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/teuchos/core/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/teuchos/core/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/kokkos/core/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/kokkos/core/src -I/usr/include -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/teuchos/comm/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/teuchos/remainder/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/teuchos/numerics/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/aztecoo/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/aztecoo/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/galeri/src-xpetra -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/galeri/src-xpetra/../src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/galeri/src-xpetra/../src/Utils -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/galeri/src-xpetra/../src/Headers -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/galeri/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/galeri/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/galeri/src/Maps -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/galeri/src/CRSMatrices -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/galeri/src/FiniteElements -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/sup/Matrix -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/sup/StridedMap -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/sup/BlockedCrsMatrix -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/sup/Cloner -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/xpetra/sup -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/ext -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/xpetra/ext -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/CrsGraph -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/CrsMatrix -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/DistObject -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/Export -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/Headers -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/Import -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/Map -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/MultiVector -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/Operator -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/Platform -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/RowGraph -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/RowMatrix -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/Utils -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/Utils/ForwardDeclaration -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/xpetra/src/Vector -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/xpetra/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/tpetra/core/ext -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/tpetra/core/ext -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/tpetra/core/inout -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/tpetra/core/inout -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/tpetra/core/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/tpetra/core/src/kokkos_refactor -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/tpetra/core/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/tpetra/tsqr/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/tpetra/tsqr/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/tpetra/classic/LinAlg -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/tpetra/classic/NodeAPI -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/tpetra/classic/NodeAPI -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/tpetra/classic/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/tpetra/classic/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/ThreadPool/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ThreadPool/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/tpetra/kernels/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/tpetra/kernels/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/tpetra/kernels/src/impl -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/kokkos/containers/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/kokkos/containers/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/kokkos/algorithms/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/kokkos/algorithms/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/MY_BUILD/packages/pliris/src -I/home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/pliris/src    -c /home/shuang/trilinos-12.0.1-Source/packages/ForTrilinos/example/ADT_3D_Burgers_6th_Pade/scalar_field.F90 -o CMakeFiles/ForTrilinos_ADT_3D_Burgers_6th_Pade.dir/scalar_field.F90.o -save-temps
```

The whole error message:

```
scalar_field.s: Assembler messages:
scalar_field.s:24649: Error: junk `@104.5037' after expression
scalar_field.s:24655: Error: junk `@104.5037' after expression
scalar_field.s:24658: Error: junk `@104.5037' after expression
scalar_field.s:24687: Error: junk `@105.5038' after expression
scalar_field.s:24689: Error: junk `@105.5038+8' after expression
scalar_field.s:24691: Error: junk `@105.5038+16' after expression
scalar_field.s:24704: Error: junk `@104.5037' after expression
scalar_field.s:24720: Error: junk `@104.5037' after expression
scalar_field.s:24732: Error: junk `@104.5037' after expression
scalar_field.s:24741: Error: junk `@105.5038' after expression
scalar_field.s:24743: Error: junk `@104.5037' after expression
scalar_field.s:24752: Error: junk `@105.5038' after expression
scalar_field.s:24754: Error: junk `@105.5038+8' after expression
scalar_field.s:24756: Error: junk `@105.5038+16' after expression
scalar_field.s:25435: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
scalar_field.s:25436: Error: bad expression
scalar_field.s:25436: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `1'
scalar_field.s:25437: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
scalar_field.s:25438: Error: bad expression
scalar_field.s:25438: Error: symbol `DA' is already defined
scalar_field.s:30617: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
scalar_field.s:30625: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
```

The assembly code around line 24649 and 24655 of scalar_field.s is

```
.LBB518:
    .loc 1 92 0
    movq    DA@104.5037(%rip), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    jne .L898
    .loc 1 92 0 is_stmt 0 discriminator 2
    movl    $56, %edi
    call    malloc
    movq    %rax, DA@104.5037(%rip)
```

The code around line 25435 is

```
viscous_param.5024:
    .long   2617245703
    .long   1069722282
    .local  DA@104.5037
    .comm   DA@104.5037,8,8
    .local  DA@105.5038
    .comm   DA@105.5038,24,16
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
```

It seems `DA@` or the decimal point is the one causing the problem, but I am not sure why and how to fix it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Run the failed command manually, with the `-save-temps` switch added to the build flags. That should save your temporary files. The error looks strange though. Also specify what architecture you are on.

Comment: @Jester I am running on x86_64. I re-run that command and the compiler does not complain, which is weird. -save-temps does not save any temp files either.

Comment: Congratulations! You found a bug in the gcc compiler. Follow the instructions on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/ (but only after you verified that the compiler bug still exists in a more current versions of gcc, most current Linux distros are on 4.9, with 5.0 looming on the horizon).